# Assigning IDs to villages which may have duplicate names?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap

I have more than 150 village points, each with a village name attribute `village`. The same village name may appear on multiple points.

I want to assign individual IDs for each village name, say `vill_A = 1`, `vill_B = 2`, and so on. I tried to calculate `[village]`, but it didn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you wanting to assign a number to a village based on alphabetical order?  Or do you just want a unique number for each village regardless of village name order?

Comment: Thanks Baltok, I don't care about alphabetical order, just unique numbers will do ..., though alphabetical order would be more helpful to keep track of things you know ...

Answer (score 5):

The best way to handle the unique values where there can be duplicates is to use a Python dictionary to link the Village name to the id number.

Here is an example Python field calculation code block:

```
villages = {}
id = 1
def GetID(village):
    global villages
    global id
    if not village in villages:
        villages[village] = id
        id += 1
    return villages[village]
```

Then simply call `GetID(!VillageNameField!)` for the expression.

This will create an empty Python dictionary called `villages`.  Then, for each record in the Village Name Field it will remember if it has already assigned an id number to that village based on whether it already exists in the dictionary.  If the village does not already exist in the dictionary it will assign it the next sequential id number.  Finally, it returns the id number associated with the village from the dictionary whether it was already there or had to be added.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with @Brad Nesom that calculating a field based on FID or OBJECTID is the simplest way, although if for some reason you need a python approach in the field calculator, try this calculation on a new integer field:

```
rec=0   
def autoIncrement():   
 global rec 
 pStart = 1  
 pInterval = 1   
 if (rec == 0):     
  rec = pStart     
 else:  
  rec += pInterval   
 return rec
```

Add to the box below the code block:

```
autoIncrement()
```

Press OK

Answer (score 3):

Probably the quickest way is,

1. create a new field for the values. i.e. [vill_id]
2. cacluate the oid (FID) into the vill_id.

[image]

Comment: the same village name appears many times, therefore the village has many FIDs; I just found the following code, but it doesn't work: Convert String to Short Integer:

MyInt = CInt( ["field name"] )
or CLng, CDbl
"field name"= MyInt

Comment: Create a summary table of all the possible village names, then run Brad's script on that table. Then you could do a join with the original data and copy that uniqueID over.

Comment: @ToNoY that would have been useful information to include in your question.

Comment: Simple solution is to combine the answers from @kenbuja (summary statistics on village fieldname) and BradNesom (add/calculate new field equal to OID/FID) then [join field](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Join_Field/001700000065000000/) by village fieldname to the original attribute table.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for any programming solution, you  may think about creating a dictionary.
`IDictionary<string, List<int>> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();`

Here,

- Key = Village_name
- Value = List of oid

Now you can assign values for all these oids or whatever you want.